# How to add image src to the state in multi step form in react

Tags: reactjs, default-value, react-props, setstate, react-state-management

**TLDR**
I'm making an multiStep form for my project that is inspired from [Brad Traversy's Tutorial of making Multi-Step form in React](https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_step_form).
So as per the basic structure of this form [image]

I made a main Parent component called `Multiform` as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StepOne from './StepOne'
export class Multiform extends Component {
    state = {
    step:1,
    CountryFlag: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MeRahulAhire/country-calling-code-html/master/phone_icon.png',
    CountryCode: ''
};
handleChange = (input) => (e) => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
};

countryFlagHandler = () =>{
    this.setState({CountryFlag : this.props.state.flagImg})
  }
render() {
    const { CountryFlag, CountryCode } = this.state;
    const values = {CountryFlag, CountryCode };

    switch (step) {
        case 1:
          return(
            <StepOne
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            countryFlagHandler={this.countryFlagHandler}
            values={values}
            />

          )
         default:
             return (<h1>hello React App</h1>)

    };
}
}

export default Multiform
```

and a child component  `StepOne` as below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    export class StepOne extends Component {
        
        state = {
    flagImg: '',
};
render() {
    const { values, handleChange, countryFlagHandler } = this.props;

    const selectCountryChange = () => {
        const img = document.querySelector('#img');
        const select = document.querySelector('#country');
        img.src = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`;

        this.setState({
            flagImg: `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`
        });
        countryFlagHandler()
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="image" onChange={selectCountryChange}>  
                <img src={values.CountryFlag} id="img"/>  
            </div>
            <select id="country" onChange={handleChange('select')} defaultValue={values.select}>  
                <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>  
                <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>  
                <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>  
            </select> 
        </div>
    )
}
    }
    
    export default StepOne
```

what I'm trying to do is actually to sync and persist the data of `<Select/>` and `<img>` in `Multiform.js` Component as typically what we see in a stepper form.
But, As in the `StepOne`

```
<img src={values.CountryFlag} id="img"/>
```

the `img.src` is actually manipulated by the function `selectCountryChange` and to keep the value of `img.src` persisted I thought of creating `countryFlagHandler` in `Multiform` and importing it to `StepOne`

but when i selected any value, it gave me this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'flagImg' of undefined**

```
Registration.countryFlagHandler
C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/cfm-usersignup/src/public/form/registration.js:53
  50 |   this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  51 | };
  52 | countryFlagHandler = () =>{
> 53 |   this.setState({CountryFlag : this.props.state.flagImg})
     | ^  54 | }
  55 | 
  56 |
```

&

```
selectCountryChange
C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/cfm-usersignup/src/public/form/credential.js:31
  28 |  this.setState({
  29 |      flagImg: `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`
  30 |  });
> 31 |  countryFlagHandler();
     | ^  32 | };
  33 | return (
  34 |  <div>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to rectify my error?

[You can also checkout my project repo for more info.](https://github.com/MeRahulAhire/cfm-dev-refined/tree/master/src/public/form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shor answer**

You're getting an error because `countryFlagHandler` is not getting the value it's expected, it doesn't have access to the `StepOne` component's state. You would need to pass the value as an argument to the parent component.

```
  // flagImg will come as an argument from the child Component
   countryFlagHandler = (flagImg) =>{
      this.setState({ CountryFlag : flagImg })
   }

    const selectCountryChange = () => {
    const img = document.querySelector('#img');
    const select = document.querySelector('#country');
    img.src = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`;

    this.setState({
        flagImg: `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`
    });
    const countryFlag = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`;
    // CountryFlag would be passed as an argument
    countryFlagHandler(countryFlag);
   };
```

**Long Answer**

I would recommend refactoring your code a bit and moving all the data to the parent component rather than keeping them in two different states. And also one function would be enough to handle all the data manipulation.

Parent Component `Multiform`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import StepOne from './StepOne'
export class Multiform extends Component {
state = {
    step: 1,
    CountryFlag: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MeRahulAhire/country-calling-code-html/master/phone_icon.png',
    CountryCode: ''
};

handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const countryCode = event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-country-code');
    const countryFlagImg = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${countryCode.toLowerCase()}.webp`;

    this.setState({
        select: value,
        CountryFlag: countryFlagImg
    });
}

render() {
    const { CountryFlag, CountryCode, step } = this.state;
    const values = { CountryFlag, CountryCode };

    switch (step) {
        case 1:
            return (
                <StepOne
                    handleChange={this.handleSelectChange}
                    countryFlagHandler={this.countryFlagHandler}
                    values={values}
                />

            )
        default:
            return (<h1>hello React App</h1>)

    };
  }
}
```

And child Component `StepOne`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class StepOne extends Component {
render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src={values.CountryFlag} id="img" />
            </div>

            <select id="country" onChange={this.props.handleChange} defaultValue={values.select}>
                <option data-country-code="IN" value="91">India</option>
                <option data-country-code="US" value="1">US</option>
                <option data-country-code="GB" value="44">UK</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Running Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-lamarr-zwspd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

As I see from your code, you try to get the flagImg propery from object that doesn't exist. If I understood your logic correctly, you need to update the selectCountryChange and countryFlagHandler methods:

```
const selectCountryChange = () => {
    const img = document.querySelector('#img');
    const select = document.querySelector('#country');
    const flagImg = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`;
    img.src = flagImg;

    this.setState({
        flagImg
    });
    countryFlagHandler(flagImg)
};
```

and in the countryFlagHandler method take it from argumnets:

```
countryFlagHandler = CountryFlag =>
    this.setState({ CountryFlag })
```

Also, your logic looks pretty dirty, maybe you could generate the flagImg property, when you select a country, set it to Multiform, and finally pass it through props to StepOne.